# Calculate poisson probability percentage

Tags: python, statistics, poisson

When you use the POISSON function in Excel (or in OpenOffice Calc), it takes two arguments:

- an integer
- an 'average' number

and returns a float.

In Python (I tried RandomArray and NumPy) it returns an array of random poisson numbers.
What I really want is the percentage that this event will occur (it is a constant number and the array has every time different numbers - so is it an average?).

for example:

```
print poisson(2.6,6)
```

returns `[1 3 3 0 1 3]` (and every time I run it, it's different).

The number I get from calc/excel is 3.19 (`POISSON(6,2.16,0)*100`).

Am I using the python's poisson wrong (no pun!) or am I missing something?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is easy to do by hand, but you can overflow doing it that way.  You can do the exponent and factorial in a loop to avoid the overflow:

```
def poisson_probability(actual, mean):
    # naive:   math.exp(-mean) * mean**actual / factorial(actual)

    # iterative, to keep the components from getting too large or small:
    p = math.exp(-mean)
    for i in xrange(actual):
        p *= mean
        p /= i+1
    return p
```

Answer (score 26):

`scipy` has what you want

```
>>> scipy.stats.distributions
<module 'scipy.stats.distributions' from '/home/coventry/lib/python2.5/site-packages/scipy/stats/distributions.pyc'>
>>> scipy.stats.distributions.poisson.pmf(6, 2.6)
array(0.031867055625524499)
```

It's worth noting that it's pretty easy to calculate by hand, [too](http://www.scipy.org/doc/api_docs/SciPy.stats.distributions.html#poisson).

Comment: Alternative import would be: `from scipy.stats import poisson` then `poisson.pmf(6, 2.6)` = 0.031867055625524499

Answer (score 1):

[This page](http://numpy.sourceforge.net/numdoc/HTML/numdoc.htm#pgfId-305426) explains why you get an array, and the meaning of the numbers in it, at least.