# How do I calculate a Poisson number in Scala

Tags: scala, statistics

There is no standard library function to do this. How can I do it efficiently?

Answer (score 3):

Scala Breeze, http://www.scalanlp.org/ has a Poisson class in its stats.distributions package.

```
case class Poisson(mean: Double)(implicit rand: RandBasis = Rand)
```

Answer (score 0):

I translated [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280797/calculate-poisson-probability-percentage-in-python) to Scala:

```
def recursive_poisson_helper(m:Long, r:Long, p:Double, i:Long):Double = {
  if (r == i) {
    p
  } else {
    recursive_poisson_helper(m, r, (p * m) / (i + 1), i + 1)
  }
}

def efficient_poisson(m:Long, r:Long): Double = {
  val p = math.exp(-m)
  recursive_poisson_helper(m, r, p, 0)
}
```

Comment: `i` should probably be a `Long` as well otherwise you shouldn’t really test for equality.

Comment: And the function names don't follow Scalas style guide, there are all these unnecessary curly braces and `recursive_poisson_helper` should be a inner function.